# Kubernetes pod service curl issue

Tags: kubernetes

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqLmE.jpg)

Hi Team did anyone faced this issue
I am trying to curl ngnix through service ip its connecting but when using service name shows error both are on same name space as well

trying to curl service with help ip is working wereas service name its not working or responding both pods are on same namespace